# gson.fromJson Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY because of how the object is stored

Tags: android, json, gson

this is not a duplicate, hear me out

I'm converting an object to json and storing it in my sqlite database

```
db.execSQL("insert into favorites (obj) values ('"+g.toJson(items.get(getAdapterPosition()),Hotel.class)+"') ;");
```

when i retrieve it from the database and convert it back to an object using gson.from json i get this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path
```

but i'm using no arrays here, i'm just dealing with one single object at a time, i decided to log the json to the logcat before storing and after retrieving it, and this is what i get

before storing, a perfectly fine object the way i intended it to be

```
D/JSON: {"id":"IQPARAUB","location":"PARIS - 33 RUE DAUPHINE","name":"HOTEL D AUBUSSON","price":"540.0EUR"}
```

after retrieving it i got this:

```
D/JSON: [B@1d9cd22
```

you see that [ in the beginning of the object, that's what's causing the error, the Gson understands that this is an array because of the [ at the start..

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added [  ] before and after my JSON object in the exec sql statement + took the advice of the comment above and it works..for now
the code became thus:

```
db.execSQL("insert into favorites (obj) values ('["+g.toJson(items.get(getAdapterPosition()),Hotel.class).toString()+"]') ;");

//and when retrieved:

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type hotelListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Hotel>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Hotel> h = gson.fromJson(json, hotelListType );
```

this works

Answer (score 0):

When you add object in database at that time it is object(raw for database), but when you retrieve with `select *` condition at that time it returns list of rows(list of object, even if there is only 1 record). That's why it is giving error of `but was BEGIN_ARRAY`.

So you must retrieve in list like this:

```
Type hotelListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Hotel>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Hotel> hotelArray = gson.fromJson(hotelJson, hotelListType );
```

Comment: i got this after applying your solution "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $[0]"